# How to use mutex to lock on a specific value or identifier in golang

Tags: go, synchronization, locking, mutex

I want to avoid any race condition while updating the balance. Below is the example code

```
type BalanceHandler struct {
  repo      Repository
  provider  Provider
}

func(h *BalanceHandler) AddToBalance(userID int64, amount int64){
  user := h.repo.GetUser(userID)

  bal := h.provider.GetBalance(user.Email())
  newBalance := bal + amount
  h.provider.UpdateBalance(user.Email(), newBalance)
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to create mutex specifically for the `userID` so that different users are allowed concurrent access but for the same `userID` the access should be synchronised

Comment: I'm not a db expert, but if this is accessing a database (Postgres or other similar), I would think you'd let the database engine handle the details of concurrent access. That is something specific to your dbms and its configuration. Also, we have no idea what happens in `Repository` and `Provider`. It seems to me that synchronization should happen at a lower level, maybe by using a transaction. Perhaps this [Go-specific article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/db-dead-lock-complete-case-study-using-golang-15dd754e5cb8) will help. I didn't vote on your question, but that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @BennyJobigan thanks. The problem is the provider does not use database. It communicates to the third part rest api

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense, there is no shared `userID` in this example. If there is a shared source of data, then you must protect the data at that source, be it in a internal data structure or a remote database.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on several things not evident from the code.

If `repo.GetUser` returns the same `user` instance for the same userID, and if that user is a pointer to a user struct, then you can add a mutex to that user, lock it after you get it, and unlock it when you're done.

Another option is to have a shared `map[string]struct{}` object, and record locked user IDs. You need a mutex to protect that map.

Comment: repo reads from postgres database. Not sure if it returns the same instance for same userID

Comment: If it is coming from a database, it will not return the same instance